# How to solve MySQLDAC HTTP Tunnel connection

Tags: mysql, http, delphi, tunnel

I want to connect to MySQL database using HTTP Tunnel (because port for remoting database is closed). I used mysqlDAC vcl for Delphi, when I was in design mode, i used `GridView` to display its data successfully.

But the problem when i compile the project, I always get this error :

```
Project WP.exe raised exception class HttpException with message 'Error on data reading from the connection:
A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall.
Socket Error Code: 10004($2714)'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.
```

Can somebody help me to solve this problem? I think my connection setup is correct, because I can display the data on `DBGrid` when I set connection is true.